# same operands different results within same code same machine

Tags: floating-point, fortran, fortran90

Same operands produce different results with REAL type single precision in fortran90 language, and it appears to be compiler options give different results.

```
real   , dimension(n_pft)    :: sapwood_ratio
real   , dimension(n_pft)    :: qsw
real   , dimension(n_pft)    :: SLA
!these 4 variables are also real type
sla_scale =  0.1 * C2B
sla_inter =  2.4
sla_slope = -0.46
leaf_turnover_rate(2)          = 1.0
leaf_turnover_rate(3)          = 0.5
leaf_turnover_rate(4)          = 1./3.
leaf_turnover_rate(12)          = 1.0
leaf_turnover_rate(13)          = 0.5
leaf_turnover_rate(14)          = 1./3.


  sapwood_ratio(1:17) = 3900.0
    SLA( 2) = 10.0**(sla_inter + sla_slope * log10(12.0/leaf_turnover_rate( 2))) * sla_scale
    SLA( 3) = 10.0**(sla_inter + sla_slope * log10(12.0/leaf_turnover_rate( 3))) * sla_scale
    SLA( 4) = 10.0**(sla_inter + sla_slope * log10(12.0/leaf_turnover_rate( 4))) * sla_scale
    SLA(12) = 10.0**(sla_inter + sla_slope * log10(12.0/leaf_turnover_rate(12))) * sla_scale
    SLA(13) = 10.0**(sla_inter + sla_slope * log10(12.0/leaf_turnover_rate(13))) * sla_scale
    SLA(14) = 10.0**(sla_inter + sla_slope * log10(12.0/leaf_turnover_rate(14))) * sla_scale
```

Everything up to here matches perfectly, but when I calculate

```
qsw(1:4)    = SLA(1:4)   / sapwood_ratio(1:4)    
qsw(5:13)   = SLA(5:13)  / sapwood_ratio(5:13)
qsw(14:15)  = SLA(14:15) / sapwood_ratio(14:15)
```

When I run this on the cluster I get

```
qsw(3)  0.0029858516063541173934937
qsw(13) 0.0029858518391847610473633
```

In my local machine

```
qsw(3)  0.0029858518391847610473633
qsw(13) 0.0029858518391847610473633
```

But they should have the same exact value, just like elements 2/12 and 4/14. Further, other similar calculations match as they should. The same code works just fine on another machine, and with same wrapper mpif90, but with gfortran, as a loader and slightly different compiling options,both have -O3. Regardless, why is this calculation not producing the same result on the same machine?
When i compile with these options this result works but it's not optimized.

```
USE_INTERF=0
   F_OPTS= -FR -O0 -recursive  -check all -g -debug extended -debug-parameters used        \
     -fpe0 -no-ftz -traceback -ftrapuv -fp-stack-check -implicitnone                 \
           -assume byterecl -warn unused -warn uncalled -warn usage -gen-interfaces
   C_OPTS= -O0 -DLITTLE  -g -traceback
   LOADER_OPTS=$(F_OPTS)
```

And this is the other option which produced this error

```
USE_INTERF=1
   F_OPTS= -FR -O3 -recursive -traceback -assume byterecl
   C_OPTS= -O3 -DLITTLE -traceback
   F_LOWO_OPTS=-FR -O2 -recursive -traceback -assume byterecl
   LOADER_OPTS=$(F_OPTS)
```

Comment: It seems to me that the title "same machine" is wrong ... you have different results on different machines (local machine vs cluster).  Also slightly different compiler options.  Both could effect floating point calculations and lead to different results, e.g., different internal representation, different order of operations, ...

Comment: You can improve floating-point portability by using `kind` parameters.

Comment: @M.S.B. good point about the same machine, but it's true that on the same machine, with calculations that are independent of order should give the same results.

Comment: ok It's definitely some compiler options, just recompiled and it's doing the right calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inconsistencies were caused by the compiling options. Compiling with alone 'O0' or compiling with 'O2' or 'O3' in addition to -fp source, solve the issue. It was a problem with floating point math.